# AdapterViewFlipper in app widget: setPendingIntentTemplate() and setOnClickFillInIntent() not working

Tags: android, android-adapterview, android-appwidget

I am changing a ListView in my app widget to an AdapterViewFlipper. The problem is, I need to handle a click on an item. It worked perfectly to set a pending intent template with setPendingIntentTemplate() to the whole ListView and set a fillInIntent with setOnClickFillInIntent() to each of its items. But now, with AdapterViewFlipper, it doesn't work anymore. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must not call setOnClickFillInIntent() with the id of the item's root view. Use any child view instead.

Comment: Thanks buddy you save my job.