# get current child index of AdapterViewFlipper in a widget

Tags: android, widget

I have a widget with 5 pages cycling with AdapterViewFlipper. When I click on current page, I want to open the browser to a specified web page (5 pages -> 5 webpages).

I need to get the current position to assign the webpage on click.

How do I get current child index of `AdapterViewFlipper`?

Comment: Try keeping track of the current view based off the last requested view in the RemoteviewsFactory

Comment: Please have a look at following link: 
It solved my problem. Bigggg thanks 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958186/adapterviewflipper-in-app-widget-setpendingintenttemplate-and-setonclickfilli

Answer (score 0):

I would put the position as an extra in the click intent. When the item is clicked you can then extract the position and open the browser that you want. something like the following in your RemoteViewsFactory:

```
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.flipper_widget);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(Constants.Extras.PAGE_NUMBER, position);
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(resId, intent);
    return rv;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should  setOnClickListener.... and yourflipper.getDisplayedChild(); it will return the position of the child clicked